# Probability of selecting red balls from a bag

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, sampling, balls-in-bins, bootstrap-sampling

I am trying to solve this problem but getting stuck in the general case.
Here is the problem statement:

A bag contains a total of N balls. Out of which M balls are red, and N-M balls are blue. Here M < (N-M).

Now, consider sampling with replacement.
In each sampling step, the probability of selecting a red ball is 0.9/M, while the probability of selecting a blue ball is 0.1/(N-M).

What is the probability that after M*k rounds of sampling, only (M-i) red balls are selected (Here 0 <= i <= M )?

If M = 1, this reduces to a simple instance, and the required probability is (1/N)^k, but not sure for M > 1.

Here is what I think the answer should be for M>1:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{M} \left( \frac{0.9}{M}\right)^{k(M-i)} \left( \frac{0.1}{N-M} \right)^{ik}
$$

Is the above equation correct? Any suggestions?

Comment: $0.9/M + 0.1/(N-M)$ won't sum to $1.$

Comment: @trueblueanil Sorry for the ambiguity. In the above question: 0.9/M is the probability of selecting 1 red ball. So total probability for all red balls is 0.9 and similarly, total probability for all blue balls is 0.1

Comment: You have unnecessarily adopted a notation which makes the problem look unnecessarily complicated. If draws are with replacement, and probabilities are constant from draw to draw, isn't it just the binomial distribution  ?

Comment: @trueblueanil The problem is slightly different. Here the target is to not just sample the red balls M times, but instead it is to sample each red ball. Maybe I should mention that the balls are numbered and the objective is to determine the probability of sampling all the M balls after M*k sampling with replacement iterations.